# How to sync mouse and keyboard operations between different processes or apps in Mac OS?

Tags: input, operating-system

I find a similar question online but it is sharing mouse and keyboard between 2 or more pcs, but what I want is to input the same mouse and keyboard operations between different processes in one computer. Is there any chance to do this?

Comment: Can you give a clarifying example of how such a thing would work?

Comment: For example, I start 2 chrome browser, and I input a question in one browser, and I want another browser to input the same question, and when I press enter, the two browser start search the same question.

Comment: Does [this kind of a thing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400255/x11-mirror-input-to-multiple-windows) resemble what you want?

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thank you so much, should I delete this question cause there is a similar one?

Comment: It's similar but on a different site, so going by best practices described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates), I'll leave the link as an answer for other people on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [xlax tool](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/xlax/xlax.1.en.html) allows you to send mirror inputs to multiple X windows.

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400255/x11-mirror-input-to-multiple-windows